# Angular CLI get current port used

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In Angular CLI you can set custom port with the `--port` command, `--port=4201` for example.

What I need to do is somehow get this port value so I can point to the correct server in my code but I'm unable to find such a way.

The reason for this is because if I use the default `4200` like this:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  host: 'http://localhost:4200'
}
```

Then I won't be able to use `--port` without the code breaking.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to have the environment config to point at the correct port at build time, you need to set up yourself a mecanism that'll get the correct port.

You could create your own run script (npm/sh/...), pass the port to that script. Then, that script will:

1. Modify the port in the environment.ts file
2. Start ng serve with the --port option

If you just want to use current host/port at runtime, you can just get it using

```
let host = `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host}`
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this in a e2e (protractor) test where `window` is not defined?

Comment: It always taking a single slash(/) instead of a double slash(//). Any idea how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 2):

You can get port number with following command:

```
window.location.port // it will give you port number
```

```js
let url = `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}`

// if port is specified in the url then it will be shown to you
if(window.location.port) {
  url += `:${window.location.port}`
}

let html = document.getElementById("portDiv")
html.innerHTML = url;
```

```html
<div id="portDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using following lines for changing port after your app start then it will not work.

```
export const environment = {
 production: false,
 host: 'http://localhost:4200'
}
```

But if you have .angular-cli.json file then change following lines to change port :
`{
    "defaults": {
        "serve": {
            "port": 8080
        }
    }
}`

Comment: This is not what I'm asking. I know how to set the port but I need to get the port being used.